Line chart displays incomplete data when adding multiple datasets
I have an issue with my chart. When I only update the temperature, the graph will be okay. But when I add the humidity, the chart is only filling up halfway:

// Declare chart variables
let temperatureChart;
let humidityChart;

// Function to create the temperature and humidity charts
function createCharts() {
    const ctxTemp = document.getElementById('temperatureChart').getContext('2d');
    const ctxHum = document.getElementById('humidityChart').getContext('2d');

    // Create the temperature chart
    temperatureChart = new Chart(ctxTemp, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: [],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Temperature (°C)',
                data: [],
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                borderWidth: 2,
                fill: false,
                tension: 0.4  // Smooth the line
            },{
                label: 'Humidity (%)',
                data: [],
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                borderWidth: 2,
                fill: false,
                tension: 0.4  // Smooth the line
        }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                x: {
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Time'
                    }
                },
                y: {
                    min: 0,  // Minimum value for temperature
                    max: 60, // Maximum value for temperature
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                    }
                }
            },
            animation: {
                duration: 0  // Disable animation to make it feel more real-time
            }
        }
    });

    // Create the humidity chart
    humidityChart = new Chart(ctxHum, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: [],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Humidity (%)',
                data: [],
                borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                borderWidth: 2,
                fill: false,
                tension: 0.4  // Smooth the line
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                x: {
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Time'
                    }
                },
                y: {
                    min: 0,   // Minimum value for humidity
                    max: 100, // Maximum value for humidity
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Humidity (%)'
                    }
                }
            },
            animation: {
                duration: 0  // Disable animation to make it feel more real-time
            }
        }
    });
}

// Function to update the charts with new data
function updateCharts(data) {
    const currentTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'});  // Get current time as "hh:mm:ss AM/PM"
    
    // Update the display box with the latest data
    document.getElementById('temperature').textContent = `${data.temperature}°C`;
    document.getElementById('humidity').textContent = `${data.humidity}%`;

    // Add the new data points to the charts
    temperatureChart.data.labels.push(currentTime);
    temperatureChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(data.temperature);
    humidityChart.data.labels.push(currentTime);
    humidityChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(data.humidity);

    // Update the charts
    temperatureChart.update();
    humidityChart.update();
}

window.onload = function() {
    createCharts();
    setInterval(fetchData, 1000);
}

How do I fix this?

you seem to have mistakenly added the humidity dataset in the temperatureChart which might be causing the issue, in essence temperatureChart has 2 datasets

The image you added doesn't match the code you posted. In the image, you have one chart with two datasets, and the error there is probably the fact that you call temperatureChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(data.temperature); twice for the same chart; the code results in these two charts, that is almost OK except the fact that you have on the first chart a dataset called "humidity" that is never updated, as indicated by @ClintonNjiru
